# segmentation fault when assigning a value to de-referenced double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have wrote this function to calculate average of values at odd or even indices of a uint32 array:

```
void average_uint32_t(uint32_t * begin, uint32_t *end,
            uint8_t skip, uint32_t **result){

    //safety check
    if(begin == end || begin > end) {
        printf("begin and end pointer does not belong to an array\n");
        *result = 0; //set pointer to null
        return;
    }

    uint64_t sum = 0;
    uint32_t count = 0;

    while(begin <= end) {
        sum += *begin;
        count++;
        printf("count=%d,value=%d,sum=%lu\n", count, *begin, sum);
        begin += skip;
    }

    **result = ((uint32_t)(sum/count)); //segmentation fault here
    printf("result=%d\n", **result);
}
```

I test the function like this:

```
//BUFF_SIZE = 8
uint32_t buffer[BUFF_SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

uint32_t * average = 0; //memory to get result back

//even indices => 0,2,4,6
average_uint32_t(buffer, buffer + BUFF_SIZE - 1, 2, &average);
printf("average of even elements = %d\n", *average);

//odd indices => 1,3,5,7
average_uint32_t(buffer + 1, buffer + BUFF_SIZE, 2, &average);
printf("average of odd elements = %d\n", *average);
```

But the program hits a segmentation fault when hitting the assignement of the result to the average (as I commented in the function code). Here is the output:

```
count=1,value=0,sum=0
count=2,value=2,sum=2
count=3,value=4,sum=6
count=4,value=6,sum=12
Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
```

What am I doing wrong? I guess a single pointer for the average function can fix the problem? but why the double pointer does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `uint32_t *average` is not pointing to valid memory area.

Try this:

```
uint32_t uiAverage = 0;
uint32_t *average = &uiAverage;
```

More better will be to use `double` instead of `uint_32_t` since average can be a floating point number. So if you are planning to use double then you also need to change the line

`**result = ((uint32_t)(sum/count));`
to
`**result = ((double)sum/(double)count));`

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, good point, but why  it does not point to a valid memory address in the beginning?

Comment: @SaeidYazdani: `uint32_t *average` is a pointer and `uint32_t *average=0;` simply means `uint32_t *average = NULL;`. So if you understand what it means to initialize a pointer to `NULL` then it will be obvious to you that `0` is most probably a restricted memory location on most platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You define `average` as a null pointer. It is Undefined Behaviour to dereference a null pointer, and in most Unix flavours, it gives a segmentation violation.

You must either use a single pointer *pointing to a real variable*, or if you want to use a double pointer, average **must** point to an existing variable.